# Qt Creator Android Debugging - cannot see variables

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging, android-ndk

I have upgraded to Qt5.5 from 5.1.1.  Since then, when I create a **stock** project on android and run a **debug** build - which is physically deployed to an android device - I cannot see any variables in the watch view.

This is without even using a shared library.

Debugging and showing variables used to function correctly before I moved to Qt5.5.  Given that my android environment and dependencies (`ant`, `ndk`, etc) have not changed, I suspect this is something to do with either Qt or the configuration of it.

Note that: `show solib-search-path` **does** include the path to my debug binary/object files. I was hoping Qt would shield me from a lot of the issues with native C++ on Android, but that has not been the case. How do I fix this issue? Is there an easy way to debug shared libraries (my own or others) that are loaded via `dlopen()`?

Comment: Android has moved to using gradle in Android Studio instead of ant+eclipse combo.  Using gradle in Qt Creator has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Even when using Gradle it still doesn't show variables in the expressions window: <no such value>  
I **think** gradle is working because I had to make changes to a gradle.build file to fix some spurious 'android.buildToolsVersion is missing' error.  
Any further ideas?  
I'm getting frustrated!  I end up not writing any code but wasting time trying to create a usable environment.  I know that there are complications with cross compilation and deploying to a non-native architecture but it really shouldn't be this difficult! Grrrr  
  
Any further ideas from anyone would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh and thank you grammar police for editing my original posting.  It's really interesting that this happens on this site.  I certainly wasn't aware of it.  Please feel free to edit this comment as well.